# Prevent hijacking IPs in KVM/libvirt

Tags: routing, vps, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

How can I prevent a VM user/client from accessing IP addresses he doesn't own but are routed over the same bridge on KVM/Libvirt?

IP addresses are routed to a cisco switch vLan consisting of a /24 254 usable addresses eg. 105.100.1.0/24.

Here is an example of the setup.

```
VM1 - 105.100.1.5
VM2 - 105.100.1.6
VM3 - 105.100.1.7
```

How can I prevent VM1 from accessing addresses that he doesn't own?

Answer (score 11):

You can't use switch port security on the Cisco since all the VMs will be sharing a physical switch port. And you can't use Linux `iptables` because the traffic is being bridged, not routed, through the hypervisor machine. But you can emulate switch port security on the hypervisor with Linux `ebtables`, which is a lesser-known layer 2/3 firewall on the Linux bridge. A quick and dirty example (and likely incomplete; I don't generally bother with this):

```
# First allow some obvious stuff; might need other things I forgot about
ebtables -A FORWARD -p IPv4 -m ip --ip-source 0.0.0.0 -j ACCEPT
ebtables -A FORWARD -p IPv6 -m ip6 --ip6-source :: -j ACCEPT

# Prevent a source MAC address from using a wrong source IP
ebtables -A FORWARD -p IPv4 -s 52:54:00:70:C1:99 -m ip --ip-source ! 192.0.2.5 -j DROP
ebtables -A FORWARD -p IPv4 -s 52:54:00:A3:09:3F -m ip --ip-source ! 192.0.2.6 -j DROP
ebtables -A FORWARD -p IPv4 -s 52:54:00:18:65:2A -m ip --ip-source ! 192.0.2.7 -j DROP
```